# How to create a load more button using php, pdo and oop

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

Im trying to create a button like the one in the youtube commentaries but i cant do it, I tried creating a static variable, so every time i press a button to load more the variable will be increased but it just can be increased once, maybe a for loop can help but i dont have any idea of how to implement it. 
(Im loading the ids i have saved in a mysql database but i will change the id for the commentaries i have in other database.) Screen shots:

[image: Here´s the fist time the page is opened]
[image: It works the first time i press the button but then it is not increased]

```
<title>Pruebas</title>
<center>
<?php 
    require 'conexion.php';

    class Ver_prublicaciones extends Conexion{
        public function Ver_prublicaciones(){
            parent::__construct();
        }
        public function Ver($num){
            $sql="SELECT * FROM USUARIOS";
            $resultNum=$this->con->query($sql)->rowCount();

            $sql2="SELECT * FROM USUARIOS LIMIT 0,$num";
            $resultCon=$this->con->query($sql2);
            $array=$resultCon->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach ($array as $value){
                echo $value['ID'] . "<br>";
            }
        }

    }

    $numero;
    $numero=2;

    if(isset($_POST['cargar'])){
        $numero++;
    }


    $prueba=new Ver_prublicaciones();
    $prueba->Ver($numero);

?>

<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="cargar" value="Cargar más resultados">
</form>
</center>
```

Comment: Where's the code for the button? How is it implemented? How is this script implemented?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i added the full code but conexion.php   The button is just there it is just a test, After i can solve the problem i have i will add some code to disappear the button when there be not more results to load

Comment: So, in your code, you have hard coded `$numero = 2;` which means that it will be 2 every time you load the script. You basically just reload the page without doing anything new.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson If i take that $numero=2; out i will get an error because there are no defined number Do you have any idea of how to change that for any other thing that can help?

Comment: Check the answer I wrote...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the current value of `$numero` to be able to increase it on every click.

PHP

```
// if we got a numero value posted, use that, otherwise set it to 2 as default
$numero = isset($_POST['numero']) ? $_POST['numero'] : 2;

if(isset($_POST['cargar'])){
    $numero++;
}
```

HTML

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="numero" value="<?= $numero ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="cargar" value="Cargar más resultados">
</form>
```

Here we added the current value of `$numero` as a hidden field that gets passed on every click.